# Can't publish HTML to server using org-mode ox-publish

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

The relevant code from my .emacs is:

```lisp
(require 'ox-publish)
(require 'ox-html)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(("org-html"
     :base-directory "~/org/"
     :base-extension "org"
     :publishing-directory "/ssh:user@server:/public_html/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
     :table-of-contents: nil
     :auto-postamble nil
     )

    ("org-static"
     :base-directory "~/org/"
     :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
     :publishing-directory "/ssh:user@server:/public_html/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
     )
   ("org" :components ("org-html" "org-static"))
   )
  )
```

I get an error message which states the following:

```
byte-code: Couldn't find exit status of `test -e /public_html/'
```

It exports fine if I publish to a directory on my local machine and it was working for a minute but then stopped. Any clues?

Comment: Just to make sure, `/public_html/` exists on the remote machine and you do have read/write access to it?

Comment: Yes, the directory is present and read/writable.

Answer (score 0):

I've the impression the problem is coming from Tramp, due to your ssh: spec for the remote file location.

Try first, maybe, to use Tramp against that remote dir, and check if everything's running fine.